# In r studio, I am trying to do randomForest, but it is taking so long to run

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest

```r
myforest = randomForest(popularity ~ acousticness + danceability + duration_ms+energy +
                        instrumentalness + key + liveness + loudness + mode +
                        speechiness + tempo + valence + year,
                        ntree = 500, data = data_all, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)
```

`data_all` is my dataset and it is a big one but I haven't had this problem before. What can I be missing? any ideas? my response variable is a numeric variable.

Comment: Hello Alara. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Comment: Define "it is a big one"

Comment: How long is it taking to run? And what are the dimensions of your data? :)

Comment: It is a dataset with 16 variables and 142761 observations. I have never seen it run, I have waited for 3 hours, then restarted couple of times because I thought there was an error. Also, I get this error when I use my factor variables.

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : Can not handle categorical predictors with more than 53 categories.

Comment: some of your predictors have too many categories.. you can try to clean that up first, maybe by binning together some categories. else you have to onehot encode your categorical predictors